# How can the styling be changed on the sharepoint page so that my data in access datasheet view is visible

Tags: sharepoint, ms-access, wss-3.0

How can the styling be changed on the sharepoint page so that my data in access datasheet view is visible

Answer (score 1):

got the issue fixed, only the page property needed to be changed and it worked. Now the data sheet is visible with data inside it in balck color